# Finding the limit of $x_n=\frac{1+2^2+\cdots+n^n}{n^n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I am given $x_n=\cfrac{1+2^2+\cdots+n^n}{n^n}$ and asked to find the limit.

I can see that it looks like 
$$\frac{\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^n k^k}{n^n}$$ 
I have been trying to use the squeeze theorem. So far, I have $1=\cfrac{n^n}{n^n}\leq x_n$.

Comment: I think it doesn't have a limit. $1/n^n$ diverges

Comment: It limits to 1. Split the fraction into two parts.

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/76991/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2243586/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2425778/42969 – all found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24x_n%3D%5Ccfrac%7B1%2B2%5E2%2B%5Ccdots%2Bn%5En%7D%7Bn%5En%7D%24&p=1)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Squeeze:
$$
1+2^2 + ... + n^n \leq 1+n^2 + ... + n^n = \frac{n^{n+1}-1}{n-1}
$$

Whence the given sequence is dominated by $$\frac{n^{n+1} - 1}{n^n(n-1)} = \frac{n^{n+1} -1}{n^{n+1} - n^n} = 1 + \frac{n^n - 1}{n^{n+1} - n^n} = 1 + \frac{\left(1 - n^{-n}\right)}{n - 1}$$

So the limit is $1$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: try listing terms from right to left.  For fixed $k \ge 0$

$$ \frac{(n-k)^{n-k}}{n^n} \le n^{-k} \ \text{if}\ n \ge k$$

Answer (score 2):

Consider the sequence $z_n = \frac{1+\cdots + (n-1)^{n-1}}{n^n} = x_n -1$.

Since $x^x$ is monotonic for $x\geq 1$, we have

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} k^k \leq \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} n^k < \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} k^k = \frac{n^n-1}{n-1}$$

This gives us the following string of inequalities

$$ 0 < z_n < \frac{1}{n-1}\left(1-\frac{1}{n^n}\right)$$

so $z_n \to 0$ by Squeeze theorem. Thus $x_n \to 1$.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, by [Stolz-Cesaro](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem)

$$x_n=\frac{a_n}{b_n}=\cfrac{1+2^2+\cdots+n^n}{n^n}\to 1$$

indeed

$$\frac{a_{n+1}-a_n}{b_{n+1}-b_n}=\cfrac{(n+1)^{n+1}}{(n+1)^{n+1}-n^n}=\frac{1}{ 1-\frac{1}{n+1} \frac{1}{\left(1+\frac 1 n\right)^n} }\to \frac{1}{\frac 1{1-0\cdot \frac 1e}}=1$$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/77001/42969 is already an answer to one of the many duplicate targets.

Comment: Also here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2425842/42969.

Comment: @MartinR I see now. Thanks to have pointed it out as further reference.